# Modificar links css/js com Grunt após concatenar e minificar

Tags: javascript, css, aplicação-web, grunt

Estou usando Grunt no meu projeto, consigo concatená-los e minificá-los conforme desejado.
Porém preciso trocar os links da minha página para os arquivos minificados. Por exemplo:

De:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/arquivo1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/arquivo2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/arquivo3.js"></script>
</head>
```

Para:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/arquivo.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Gostaria de saber se há um plugin para isso (deve ter) e como configurá-lo.

---

EDIT

Apenas uma página (index.html) contém os links. As outras páginas estão ligadas usando AngularJS.
Também estou usando Node.js para auxiliar com o Grunt.

Comment: Estás a usar Node? esse head existe em cada página ou tens um ficheiro com o head que é incluído em todas as páginas?

Comment: Sim, estou usando Node.js também. Tenho apenas uma página com os links pois uso AngularJS para SinglePage Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem alguns. Eu, particularmente, utilizo este: https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml

Gosto desse plugin pois ele permite não só renomear os arquivos, como recriar blocos ou remover, de acordo com sua necessidade e mesmo que aquele código não esteja ligado com algum outro processo do grunt.

Por exemplo:

```
<!-- build:remove -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Algum código de teste
    </script>
<!-- /build -->
```

Após fazer o processo, aquele código será removido do arquivo.

Existem diversas opções que você pode ver na documentação.

### Importante!

Note que esse processo não estará vinculado com outro (pelo menos eu não conheço um método de fazer isso), ou seja, após concatenar e minificar o arquivo JS, ele **não** irá fazer o processo em html automático. Assim como é feito para o JS, deverá ser feito para o HTML.

**Obs.:** Vale ressaltar que para essa técnica é recomendável que você mova TODOS os arquivos para um novo diretório exclusivo para *production* assim ele não vai interferir com o seu código de desenvolvimento.